# Finding the most accurate indoor navigation API

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-api-3

I am searching for API that allows to implement app with indoor navigation (navigation inside one specific building). I found some API's like [google map indoor navigation](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/indoormaps/), [meridian](http://www.meridianapps.com/products) and [insiteo](http://www.insiteo.com/joomla/index.php/en/products/93-insiteo/products/141-pathfinding-and-navigation-api).

I am asking what of those (or maybe others) has the best and most exact navigation, based on WiFi triangulation and other location-finding ways. I search for the most accurate one, so please give you opinions about them and others and explain them.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it heavily depends on your environment, budget, target group, etc. But I can recommend you to give indoo.rs a try - which offers an SDK for cross-platform indoor localization.

PS: I work for indoo.rs.

Comment: I have a requirement to develop an indoor navigation system in a retail store, the consumers should be able to search a product and the app should guide them to the right location where the product is. Before buying the product, I would like to know whether this usecase can be achieved.

Comment: @anoop4real Try asking your question at http://support.indoo.rs/

Comment: @TomTasche is it possible for us to know whether we are indoor or outdoor using the indoo.rs SDK ?

Comment: @VyshakhAmarnath yes I think so (I don't work for indoo.rs anymore).

Comment: @TomTasche, Assuming that you still work at indoor.rs , I need a help in implementing the indoo.rs . I am able to set the zones, measure fingerprints of my venue using the MMT . But when coming to Android , I am not able to draw the Route. If you can help me, I can elaborate more here. Also, I posted a question in support forum: https://indoors.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/1/DESK-502 . Still waiting for the reply.