# API for Indoor navigation system

Tags: android, navigation, maps

I'm building web service taking estimated point and the destination point from client and return set of shortest path points.(I'm defined nodes and edges for the map)
Now I want to build indoor navigation system by loading map image and draw shortest path line and directions.
Is there API for Android to doing that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding the most accurate indoor navigation api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531184/finding-the-most-accurate-indoor-navigation-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is. http://indoo.rs/

It's actually meant for indoor localization, but it does indoor navigation just as well!